# Writing/reading from a holdingsregister on Modbus TCP does not work

Tags: matlab, tcp, simulink, modbus, matlab-deployment

I have connected a PC to a Bachmann M1 Controller using Modbus tcp/ip connection in MATLAB. Now I want to read/write variables from/to a Simulink model. So I have created variables in Simulink using SVI-SW blocks (provided by Bachmann M-target), and mapped those variables to holdingsregisters and given them indexes of 0 and 200.

The following images are the configurations in the Bachmann's software called Solution Center:

[Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SSrl.png)

[Some other configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJD4X.png)

And the same variables in Simulink (the yellow S blocks having the name 'u' and 'y':

[Simulink model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beTJR.png)

After I run the Simulink model in Bachmann M1 controller using external mode, I can connect the PC to the controller from MATLAB command window:

```
>> m = modbus('tcpip', '192.168.X.XXX')

m = 

Modbus TCPIP with properties:

    DeviceAddress: '192.168.X.XXX'
             Port: 502
           Status: 'Connected'
       NumRetries: 1
          Timeout: 10 (seconds)
        ByteOrder: 'big-endian'
        WordOrder: 'big-endian'
```

Now when I want to read/write the registers using the corresponding indexes, it does not work. Writing generates the following error:

```
>> write(m, 'holdingregs', 1, 1)
The Modbus server returned an invalid address error. Address + number of values to write is out of range.
```

The index of the variable u is 0 (which is 1 in MATLAB) and u is an array of 10 elements. So I can't understand why the address is out of range.

As for the reading, I can read the corresponding indexes (1 and 201), but the result is not correct:

```
>> b = read(m, 'holdingregs', 201, 2, 'double')

b =

  1.0e-319 *

    0.8079    0.8079
```

The scope that is connected to that variable shows its value as 0.5, which is correct as I have configured the initial value of a delay block that way. But read function displays a negligibly small value, almost 0.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Edit: Now with the same simulation, I get an error while trying to read as well:

```
>> b = read(m, 'holdingregs', 1, 1, 'double')
The Modbus server returned a read failure error.
```

What can I use to get more info about this error?

Comment: If you have SolutionCenter, expand the PLC -> System, double click Diagnostics and in the window opening select tab "System Debug Level". switching ON the normal (maybe extended as well) debug level for SVI handler may give usefull info. IO Module driver as well. In case you use de modbus.m task you can set a debug level for the task (0xFFFFFFFF will enable all debug). In case you use MBM201, find the DebugMode in the config. Finally open the TCP/IP debug console to see any debug info on the modbus connection, analyze it, and find the issue.